# VS 2019 Install-Package Automatically Updated Dependencies - How to revert?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework-core

My project uses an older version of EF Core and when I tried to run this:

Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory

It uninstalled and reinstalled a bunch of from this previous version to the latest version. Example:

Successfully uninstalled 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore X.X.X' from Project

Successfully installed 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.1' to Project

There are a bunch of others as well. Can I revert this somehow? Also, if I want to keep the InMemory package do I have to specify an older version so it does not update what I assume are these dependencies?

Comment: Specify the previous version - standard Nuget behavior

Comment: @ErikEJ Do you know of a way to revert all the packages it updated? Or do I need to do them manually one by one?

Comment: It is all in clear sight in your csproj or packages.config file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by running

Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory -Version X.X.X

This uninstalled the 5.0.1 versions and reinstalled the older version of all the dependencies that were previously updated. No other commands were needed.